# Pymongo + DJango admin panel

Tags: django, pymongo

Is it possible to use the admin panel in combination with django + pymongo?

error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

this is because DATABASES is commented out in settings.py, but in the pymongo documentation it says that it needs to be commented

I searched the Internet for information and couldn’t find a solution.